# Regarding use of ImmutableJS with React

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm developing a couple of spikes on our platform to explore certain possible directions to take as we move to using more React components.

We're using Redux and are considering how best to implement ImmutableJS.

So here's the dilemma;

- On one hand, we want our 'dumb' components to be as dumb and framework agnostic as possible.
- On the other hand, using ImmutableJS inside the components will ensure better data integrity.

Right now, we're set on using ImmutableJS in the Redux state to ensure integrity at that level, but should we go as far as using ImmutableJS at the individual component level (thereby lacing all our components with ImmutableJS code)?

Is there a generally accepted best practise for this yet?

Comment: [Don't mix immutable and mutable state](http://jlongster.com/Using-Immutable-Data-Structures-in-JavaScript), but if you're talking about local variable within a function of a component, it is fine to use plain javascript. Just do not mix whenever dealing with the state.

Comment: As for best practices there isn't really one. I'd say to start with changing parts of the redux state to immutablejs structure and change every component corresponding to that state. This can be done gradually while feeling the benefits and performance gains of using an immutable structure. Once ever property of the root store has been changed, you can change the entire store to an immutablejs structure. Hope this helps!